# Comma separated step for number input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can specify the 'step' for thousand increments when a user inputs a number. But why I cannot write '1,000'  instead of '1000' for the increment to happen with the comma separation for thousands? How to do this?

```html
<div class="input"><label for="salary">Salary</label>
<input class='inp_cont' id="salary" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" step="1000" min="0" required="" type="number"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be done if you want to stick to the `type="number"`, because:

- As Chrome reports:

  > The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
- As specification mentions:

  > value = [floating-point number](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#common.data.float)

Follow the above link to see that spec doesn't mention use of comma at all.

---

If you want to switch to `type="text"`:

```js
document.getElementById('salary').addEventListener('input', event =>
  event.target.value = (parseInt(event.target.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi, '')) || 0).toLocaleString('en-US')
);
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <label for="salary">Salary</label>
  <input class='inp_cont' id="salary" pattern="^[\d,]+$" name="salary" placeholder="Enter your salary" required="" type="text">
</div>
```